# Animate the resizing of a QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpropertyanimation

I have a QListView which I can fit to contents by calling updateGeometry. Now I want to animate it. I cant use the resizeEvent, since it is calles *after* the widget has been resized. What is the proper place to start this animation, ergo which members are called internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should leave the QListView quite and focus instead on its model. Let's say that you have something like:

```
QListView *myListView;
```

In that case you should pay attention to its model, which means:

```
QAbstractItemModel *myListModel(myListView->model());
```

You can connect some slot (depending on when you want to start the animation, before or after the data is being fetched by the views), maybe something like:

```
connect(myListModel, &QAbstractItemModel::rowsAboutToBeInserted, myHandlingObject, &MyHandlingObjectClass::myHandlingSlot);
```

or:

```
connect(myListModel, &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted, myHandlingObject, &MyHandlingObjectClass::myHandlingSlot);
```

Inside MyHandlingObjectClass::myHandlingSlot() slot you will eventually start a QPropertyAnimation. I think it's not much more than this. Hope it helps!